# Adding Gradle to PATH

Tags: terminal, bash, path

I am trying to add Gradle to my PATH.  I have used the command

```
export PATH=/myUsername/Applications/gradle-2.6/bin:$PATH
```

but when I type

```
gradle
```

I get an error "command not found."  So I went to look for .profile or .bash_profile, but neither file existed.  So I created .bash_profile, and added the line

```
export PATH=/myUsername/Applications/gradle-2.6/bin:$PATH
```

This still did not work, and I have no idea what to do from here.  When I type $PATH, I see the lines added, so I have no idea why it isn't working.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The path /myusername/Applications/gradle-2.6/bin probably doesn't exist except your personal user folder is in the root of your main volume - which would be very, very uncommon on a *nix system.

Depending on where you've installed Gradle the proper path might be:

```
/Users/myUsername/Applications/gradle-2.6/bin or
/Applications/gradle-2.6/bin
```

So change the export line to

```
export PATH=/Users/myUsername/Applications/gradle-2.6/bin:$PATH or  
export PATH=/Applications/gradle-2.6/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd not place it forward of the system's `$PATH` and do it as such.

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Applications/gradle-2.6/bin
```

If you want it first in the `$PATH`, then use:

```
 export PATH=$HOME/Applications/gradle-2.6/bin:$PATH
```